# Opposite category and contravariant functors as defined by Borceux

Tags: category-theory

> Definition. Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, the opposite category
> $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ is defined in the following way.
>
> 1. $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}):=\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$.
> 2. For $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}(X,Y):=\mathcal{C}(Y,X)$ (to avoid confusion,
>    we shall write $f^{\text{op}}:X\rightarrow Y$ for the morphism of
>    $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ corresponding to the morphism
>    $f:Y\rightarrow X$ of $\mathcal{C}$).
> 3. The composition law of $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ is given by  $$(f^{\text{op}}\circ g^{\text{op}}):=(g\circ f)^{\text{op}}$$ for
>    morphisms $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ be a contravariant functor. I want to show that $F$ is a covariant functor from $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. W.r.t. the mapping of objects nothing changes. For $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$, we have a mapping
$$\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}(X,Y)=\mathcal{C}(Y,X)\rightarrow\mathcal{D}(F(X),F(Y)),\,f\mapsto F(f).$$
Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be arrows of $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$. We have to show that $F(g\circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)$. Since $f\in\text{C}^{\text{op}}(X,Y)$ and $g\in\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}(Y,Z)$, it is the case that $f^{\text{op}}\in\mathcal{C}(Y,X)$ and $g^{\text{op}}\in\mathcal{C}(Z,Y)$. Then
$$F(g\circ f)=F((g^{\text{op}})^{\text{op}}\circ(f^{\text{op}})^{\text{op}})=F((f^{\text{op}}\circ g^{\text{op}})^{\text{op}})=?$$
I'm now stuck. Can someone please help complete this using Borceux's definition.

Comment: I think I would write $f^{\textrm{op}}$ and $g^{\textrm{op}}$ for the elements of $C^{\textrm{op}}(X,Y)$ and $C^{\textrm{op}}(Y,Z)$ rather than $f$ and $g$. It does agree with the quoted definition after all.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Right; so: $F(g^{\text{op}}\circ f^{\text{op}})=F((f\circ g)^{\text{op}})$. What would be the next step?

Comment: I find it a bit more natural to write $\circ^\mathrm{op}$ for the composition law for $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$, so that $f \circ^\mathrm{op} g = g \circ f$. Then $F(g \circ^\mathrm{op} f) = F(f \circ g) = F(g) \circ F(f)$, as desired. You could couple this with using the notation $f^\mathrm{op}$ if you'd like as well, as in $F(g^\mathrm{op} \circ^\mathrm{op} f^\mathrm{op}) = F(f \circ g) = F(g) \circ F(f) = F(g^\mathrm{op}) \circ F(f^\mathrm{op})$.

Comment: @Hayden I think Borceux means to say $f^{\text{op}}\circ^{\text{op}}g^{\text{op}}:=(g\circ f)^{\text{op}}$, no? Why on earth does he append $^{\text{op}}$ to the morphism $(g\circ f)$?

Comment: @alf262 I think Borceux is appending ${}^\mathrm{op}$ to morphisms just to make clear that, while they are *technically* the same objects as the morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, their domains and codomains are switched. So, as an object (where I mean 'object' in the context of whatever background theory you're using, probably $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and *not* object in the sense an element of $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$) $f = f^\mathrm{op}$, so $f \circ^\mathrm{op} g = f^\mathrm{op} \circ^\mathrm{op} g^\mathrm{op} = (g \circ f)^\mathrm{op} = g \circ f$.

Comment: @Hayden Ok seems to make sense. Thanks!